# iPhone/iPad Keyboard Dimming

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, ipod, iphone-softkeyboard

I am writing a universal app that will be used primarily at night.  I will need to display a keyboard but do not want the light colors of the keyboard to blind the user and/or spoil their night vision.  I do not want to have to go through the trouble to creating a custom keyboard so I thought a solution might be to place a UIView over the keyboard and give it a black background color with an alpha of 0.5 or something however, I can not figure out how to get a UIView to cover the keyboard.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Does Apple allow this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyboard is found as a subview of a new window that is added when it appears. Finding it is a little hacky and fragile (will need checking at new iOS versions, as it has changed before) but it does work and it is allowed (I do exactly this for a night mode in an app that is on the app store).

```
UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1]; // This assumes you aren't adding any new windows yourself

for(UIView *keyboard in tempWindow.subviews) 
{
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES) // This was different in an earlier version of iOS, and may well change again in the future!
    {
        [keyboard addSubview:maskView];
        break;
    }
}
```

This is done inside the method that responds to the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` object. I've not tried it on the iPad, this is iPhone code only.

The mask view is, as you say, just a plain view with a black background and some transparency. You can also use the alert keyboard style which gives a black space in between the keys.

This method does not prevent the little key flashes (the larger keys that pop up when you tap a key) from being at full brightness, unfortunately.

Comment: I did notice however, that when you split the keyboard on the iPad, this does not work correctly.  I suspect that I will need to create 2 UIView - one for each half of the keyboard...

Comment: Good spot - as I said I haven't done this on the iPad so I didn't notice that. Stuff like the split keyboard being introduced is exactly why this is a fragile way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

try applying the required changes on `inputView` property of UITextFiled/UITextArea (the one being used).